# IIF in Query Builder Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
База данных создана на MS ACCESS. Конструкция IIF в Query Builder-е Visual Studio 2015 работает непонятным образом.
Если в IIF() для условного выражения испульзую ISNULL() то Query Builder нормально работает, а если заменяю другим условием то Query Builder ругается. Может кто столкнулся с этой проблемой.

```
SELECT
  residues.storeId,
  residues.barcode,
  residues.expDate,
  residues.price,
  residues.initialQuantity,
  residues.initialCost,
  residues.inputQuantity,
  residues.inputCost,
  residues.outputQuantity,
  residues.outputCost,
  residues.restQuantity,
  residues.restCost,
  IIF(ISNULL(relatedDocument.docTypeId), 0, relatedDocument.docTypeId) AS rDocTypeId,
  IIF(ISNULL(relatedDocument.quantity), 0, relatedDocument.quantity) AS docQuantity,
  IIF(ISNULL(relatedDocument.cost), 0, relatedDocument.cost) AS docCost,
  IIF(rDocTypeId = 0, residues.restQuantity, IIF(rDocTypeId = 1, residues.restQuantity - docQuantity, residues.restQuantity + docQuantity))
FROM (residues
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
  documents.id,
  documents.docTypeId,
  documents.docDate,
  documents.storeId,
  docRows.barcode,
  docRows.expDate,
  docRows.price,
  docRows.quantity,
  docRows.cost
FROM (documents
LEFT OUTER JOIN docRows
  ON documents.id = docRows.documentId)
WHERE (documents.erased = FALSE)
AND (docRows.erased = FALSE)
AND (documents.id = ?)) relatedDocument
  ON residues.storeId = relatedDocument.storeId
  AND residues.barcode = relatedDocument.barcode
  AND residues.expDate = relatedDocument.expDate
  AND residues.price = relatedDocument.price)
WHERE (residues.erased = FALSE)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMRdH.png

Comment: *если заменяю другим условием то Query Builder ругается* А пример такого условия и текст ошибки - военная тайна?

Comment: пример такого условия:
IIF(rDocTypeId = 0, residues.restQuantity,1), а текст ошибки:
Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: *Unable to parse query text* Покажите полный текст запроса с таким IIf.

Comment: так пробовали? IIF(rDocTypeId ="0", residues.restQuantity,1)

Comment: Пробовал, так не работает, тот же сообщение уважаемый Денис...

Comment: @armenarz, попробуйте заменить строку IIF(rDocTypeId = 0, residues.restQuantity, IIF(rDocTypeId = 1, residues.restQuantity - docQuantity, residues.restQuantity + docQuantity)) на case when rDocTypeId = 0 then  residues.restQuantity when rDocTypeId = 1 then residues.restQuantity - docQuantity else  residues.restQuantity + docQuantity end

Comment: Уважаемый Денис, я и так пробовал, не помогает.